# Ramda - appendPath

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm starting on new project which uses `Ramda` and I'm looking for some function to append item to array on given path. In `Immutable.js` it is called `pushIn`. Is there any equivalent in `Ramda`?

I found working approach with combining `append`, `assocPath` and `path` but it looks quite weird.

```
const state = {
  groups: {
    1: {
      items: [1, 2]
    }
  }
}
const paths = ['groups', 1, 'items'];
const result = R.assocPath(paths, R.append(3, R.path(paths, state)), state);



Result: {
          groups: {
            1: {
              items: [1, 2, 3]
            }
          }
        }
```

Is there any easier approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something a bit different.

```js
const {over, lensPath, append} = R

const state = {groups:{1:{items:[1, 2]}}}

const addItem = (item, state) => over(lensPath(['groups', 1, 'items']), append(item), state) 

console.log(addItem(3, state))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

While there is probably a way to make this point-free, this seems readable enough as is.